# Node.js Expand compressed ISO Date Time

Tags: node.js, date, compare, isodate

Is there a simple/native way to convert a short hand ISO format to an expanded standard format? I believe that is what is causing my comparison to fail (but happy to be told otherwise).

What i believe is short hand is this

```
Short ISO Time: 20160524T054843Z
```

What i have as a normal ISO string is

```
Long ISO Time: 2016-05-18T11:46:21.982Z
```

Then when i try and compare using

```
${compareable.getHours()}:${compareable.getMinutes()}:${compareable.getSeconds()}:${compareable.getMilliseconds()}
```

I get the following

```
Time difference: NaN:NaN:NaN:NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var shortDate = '20160524T054843Z'
shortDate.replace(/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})T(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})Z$/, '$1-$2-$3T$4:$5:$6.000Z')
> "2016-05-24T05:48:43.000Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

why you don't try moment package. http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Because the script i am trying to create should be standalone and i don't really want to have to npm install and turn one file into an application. This does work tho.